# How to store data internal to a SWF

Tags: actionscript-3

I have projects I need to deliver as 1 SWF and need to store data, strings and numbers, internally that might normally get stored as an external xml or csv. Typically its a small amount of data, but could get quite huge for some projects. I figure I could store the data internally as a script or in a library text field. Are either of these methods faster to load, easier to use, etc. Or is there another method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings and numbers etc, you can just store normally as variables. For xml, images, sound etc, you have the option of embedding them using the `[Embed]` metatag. Check out http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf60546-7ff2.html and http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf60546-7ffb.html for the actual syntax behind it.

Basically it lets you keep your data in its original form, then when you compile, your data is embedded in the swf, meaning you don't need to load it, you just `new` it.

```
[Embed(source="somePic.jpg")]
public var myPicClass:Class;

...

var b:Bitmap = new myPicClass;
```